# Variabilizing folder path in SnowSQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to variabilize folder paths in SnowSQL for commands like `put` and `copy` where I could do

```
put $file_location
```

Or even

```
put file:$file_location
```

Instead of

```
put file://R:\testing\data\take_1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `define`:

```
> !define file_location=path_goes_here
> !set variable_substitution=true

> put &file_location
```

> [Substituting Variables in a Session](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#substituting-variables-in-a-session)
>
> To use a variable in a statement, use the **&variable_name** syntax. Note that variable names are case-insensitive.
>
> ...
>
> To combine a variable with text, enclose the variable reference in curly braces.
>
> ```
> select '&{snowshell}_shell';
> ```